# My Script ignores bits of code

Tags: powershell

I have this script which turns off every PC in the OUs if they run more than 2 days:

```
    function Get-LastBootUpTime {            
    param (
        $ComputerName
    )
        $OperatingSystem = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $ComputerName               
        [Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($OperatingSystem.LastBootUpTime)            
    }

    $Days = -2
    $ShutdownDate = (Get-Date).adddays($days)

    $ComputerList = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'OU=X,DC=X,DC=X' ` -Filter '*' | Select -EXP Name
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'OU=X,DC=X,DC=X' ` -Filter '*' | Select -EXP Name
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'OU=X,DC=X,DC=X' ` -Filter '*' | Select -EXP Name
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'OU=X,DC=X,DC=X' ` -Filter '*' | Select -EXP Name
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'OU=X,DC=X,DC=X' ` -Filter '*' | Select -EXP Name
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'OU=X,DC=X,DC=X' ` -Filter '*' | Select -EXP Name
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'OU=X,DC=X,DC=X' ` -Filter '*' | Select -EXP Name
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'OU=X,DC=X,DC=X' ` -Filter '*' | Select -EXP Name
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'OU=X,DC=X,DC=X' ` -Filter '*' | Select -EXP Name
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'OU=X,DC=X,DC=X' ` -Filter '*' | Select -EXP Name
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'OU=X,DC=X,DC=X' ` -Filter '*' | Select -EXP Name
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'OU=X,DC=X,DC=X' ` -Filter '*' | Select -EXP Name
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'OU=X,DC=X,DC=X' ` -Filter '*' | Select -EXP Name
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'OU=X,DC=X,DC=X' ` -Filter '*' | Select -EXP Name
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'OU=X,DC=X,DC=X' ` -Filter '*' | Select -EXP Name
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'OU=X,DC=X,DC=X' ` -Filter '*' | Select -EXP Name
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'OU=X,DC=X,DC=X' ` -Filter '*' | Select -EXP Name

    $ComputerList | foreach {
        $Bootup = Get-LastBootUpTime -ComputerName $_

        Write-Output "$_ last booted: $Bootup" | tee -Append C:\Scripts\Shutdown\log.txt

        if ($ShutdownDate -gt $Bootup) {
            Write-Output "Rebooting Computer: $_" | tee -Append C:\Scripts\Shutdown\shutdown.txt
            Stop-Computer $_ -Force -WhatIf
        }
        else {
            Write-Output "No need to reboot: $_" | tee -Append C:\Scripts\Shutdown\shutdown.txt
        }
    }
```

If I run it though, it only works with the first OU in `$ComputerList` and completely ignores the rest of it. So the Result would be something like:
"No need to Reboot PCx
Rebooting Computer PCy"

But in all of the OUs are more than 120 PCs. Anybody has an idea how to make `$ComputerList` recogniye all of the OUs and PCs that are in the different OUs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Topic is closed, I found the solution by myself.

For everyone who has the same problem: Just make a loop out for every single OU.

```
$ComputerList = x
$ComputerList1 = x
....
```